# Unable to center figures in table using parbox

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, parbox

I am trying to create a table with four figures centered and the next row should have its text centered.

[image]

As you can see, the parboxes aren't centered, I've tried several ways to fix this but am unable to do so. Thanks for your advice!

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{xxx}
\label{tab:xxx}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}} %
\hline
\parbox[c]{1em}{\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-b}}
  & \parbox[c]{1em}{\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-b}}
  & \parbox[c]{1em}{\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-b}}
  & \parbox[c]{1em}{\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-b}}\\
 \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Part} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Impactor} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Scalp} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Sphere}\\
x & x & x & x\\
x & x & x & x\\
x & x & x & x\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: what is the intention of the `\parbox` ?

Comment: @Schweinebacke  Looking at the image I guess that he want center only the first two rows, not the next rows, so change the column type seems could not help in this case.

Comment: @Chukke the `p` column is already a `\parbox` cell internally, and the optional `c` is for the *vertical* alignement and moreover is the default option, so it is useless as well.

Answer (score 5):

Simplicity is power. What about use only a `\hfil`?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|} %
\hfil\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-a} &
\hfil\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-b} &
\hfil\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-c} &
\hfil\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image} \\
\hfil Part & \hfil Impactor & \hfil Scalp & \hfil Sphere \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, that I understand your question correctly, but let me try:

[image]

Code is rather simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\caption{xxx}
    \label{tab:xxx}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{C{2.5cm}}} %
    \toprule
\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-b}
    &   \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-b}
        &   \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-b}
            &   \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{example-image-b}     \\
Part    &   Impactor    &   Scalp   &   Sphere                      \\
x   & x & x & x\\
x   & x & x & x\\
x   & x & x & x
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```